# Issue in Logic app workflow connects to eventhub

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub

I am getting below error in my logic app workflow, I have schedular->MQ->Azure EventHub connectors. I can see message coming till MQ and there is failure in eventhub with below error. Appreciate for any suggestion why this error is comming up, and how to overcome this.

"BadRequest. Http request failed as there is an error: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."

Answer (score 0):

You might be receiving this due to Authentication or certificate errors.

- You can check for the connection you are establishing while creating the event hub connector.
- Authorize access to an event hub by using a Sytem assigned managed identity.
- Try checking certificate expiration - To configure service principals with certificate credentials where Azure AD can be used to build a service principal with restricted access at the resource level. Azure Key Vault may be utilised with Azure-managed identities in both scenarios, such that the runtime environment, such as an Azure function, can get the credential from the key vault.

Also you can try checking the inner exception that is occuring and take further actions accordingly.

**REFERENCES:**
[Azure security baseline for Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/event-hubs-security-baseline#im-2-manage-application-identities-securely-and-automatically)
[Authentication a managed identity with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authenticate-managed-identity?tabs=latest#use-event-hubs-with-managed-identities)